# Spring Boot UI for Spring Security (e.g. add users roles etc)

Tags: java, grails, spring-security, spring-boot

When I worked with grails I faced a plugin https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui which allowed to CRUD Users and Roles with corresponding UI so one didn't need to write code for CRUD/filter Users and Roles. Now I work with Spring Boot and writing web-application and looking for something similar (to https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui) some dependency plugin etc which would introduce similar functionality. Is there someting similar for Spring Boot or I need to write the functionality from the scratch?

Thanks, cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think [Spring Vaadin](https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/) should manage with that.